# ¿Cómo saber cuándo una palabra o expresión se añadió al DLE?

Tags: etimología, historia, dle

Pues no hay mucho más que explicar. A veces encontramos noticias del tipo "La RAE incluirá *almóndiga* en la próxima edición del diccionario". Pero, una vez incluida la *almóndiga* (o cualquier otra palabra), ¿cómo puede saberse la fecha de la inclusión?

¿Alguien puede dar algún procedimiento fijo (alguna serie de pasos) que concluya en la obtención de esta información?

Comment: Gracias. Era más sencillo de lo que yo pensaba.  ¿Podrías ponerlo como  respuesta? Por cierto, si lo estoy haciendo bien, [precisamente _almóndiga_, está desde el principio de los tiempos](http://web.frl.es/ntllet/SrvltGUIMiscNuevoTesoro?idSesion=0000yOSgO9co5dpQ9vG_n7RAUB0:-1); o sea, que lo de su inclusión reciente es un bulo.

Comment: Exacto. Pasa lo mismo con _asín_, que la gente cree que la RAE ha incluido ese término recientemente por la gente que lo pronuncia asín, cuando en realidad lleva en el diccionario desde el principio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En la respuesta a *[Resources for learning Spanish / Recursos para aprender español](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23618/12637)*, verás que existe un [mapa de diccionarios](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/mapa-de-diccionarios). Ahí puedes consultar términos en varias versiones del diccionario desde 1780 hasta 2001 de forma simultánea. Así se puede saber cuándo se incluyó un término o cuándo se le añadió un significado nuevo.

En todo caso, el mapa de diccionarios da una idea aproximada de la fecha de inclusión. Si quieres el año exacto lo mejor es el [*Nuevo tesoro lexicográfico de la lengua española (NTLLE)*](http://ntlle.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUILoginNtlle), que no solo busca una palabra en todas y cada una de las ediciones del diccionario de la RAE desde 1780 hasta 1992, sino también en muchos otros diccionarios, incluyendo el *Covarrubias* de 1611 y el *Autoridades*, la obra de la RAE previa al DLE.